Copy/paste via virt-manager to a kvm text mode guest
I have done what's mentioned in virt-manager copy paste functionality to the vm
Environment: Ubuntu 22.04 server (VM) and Kubuntu 22.04 (virt-manager)
Installed spice-vdagent on the VM and spice-client-gtk on both VM and virt-manager system
Checked the VM definition in virt-manager:
Display Spice: Spice server, listening on all addresses
Video QXL: model QXL
Channel spice: spicevmc/virtio/com.redhat.spice.0
Rebooted the VM, closed and re-started virt-manager, spice-vdagentd is running on the guest
Tried right-clicking the mouse and Ctrl-V but nothing works.  The reason for wanting this is "What if I get in a situation where the network isn't working on the VM and need to fix it?"  This can happen if a guest is moved from one hypervisor to another, even if the same NIC driver is used, the internal NIC name may change and there's no network. The alternative of suggesting ssh isn't helpful in this situation.
Any ideas or help?  Thanks.
